# 301 redirect with special characters .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a WordPress website and I need to redirect hundreds of URLs to the homepage. My .htaccess looks like this currently...

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php[?/\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:page|mact)= [NC]
RewriteRule !^wp-admin/ /? [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The rewrites are working for how I need it to work which is redirect any links that contain **page** or **mact** on the frontend only (not backend WP). The only issue I have is with my category pages which look like this...

```
www.domain.com/category/general/page/3/?page=page
```

These category pages redirect to the homepage which I don't want so I need to exclude these types of URLs that contain 'category' from redirecting to the homepage.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change your 2nd rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:page|mact)= [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(?:wp-admin|category)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R=301,NC]
```

This will exclude `/category/...` URLs from this redirect.

Make sure to use a new browser for testing.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava :). It kind of works.
URLs like - www.domain.com/category/general/page/21/ work
but for URLs that contain '?page=page-name' at the end of the url such as; www.domain.com/category/general/page/21/?page=dog-training then these still redirect to home page which I don't want

Comment: Working great thanks :D but now my other URLs don't redirect. e.g.
'www.domain.com/?mact=dog-training' and www.domain.com/?page=dog-training